# how can we automatically turn on airplane mode when radio signal is very low in android?

Tags: android

how can we automatically turn on airplane mode when radio signal is very low in android???

Comment: I just giggled :) Why are you trying to achive this?

Comment: This will cause people's phones to unknowingly turn off when they're in the train, elevator, tunnel...  so their phone will turn off on the way to work, and they won't realise until half-way through the day...

Comment: Sounds like potentially a good idea for saving battery life, if you could add a timer to re-enable or retry every few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to listen for low signals, I don't know how to disable telephony though.